# Overlay a stacked div above another div while sliding up

Tags: css, overlay, z-index, slide

Okay so I have three divs, red, green and black stacked one below the other. When I hover on the `slider` class, I want the green and black div to slide up on hover. But I don't want the green div to hide behind the red div on hover(like it currently does), instead, it should overlay on top of the red div.

i.e on hover the red, green, and black divs should be visible, with the green div covering a part of the red div.
I've tried using absolute positioning together with z-index, but it doesn't seemt to work!

I've put the html, css and javascript in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Qsp8/

Comment: Please add the relevant code into your question (otherwise you run the risk of this question being closed as 'off topic' simply because you didn't include the [relevant/minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with the positioning. You are using slide function of jQuery. It does not actually pushes your `div` upwords. It diminishes it from bottom to top. So your green `div` is not actually moving below your red `div`. It is vanishing from bottom to top.

Here is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/8Qsp8/5/

Animated version: http://jsfiddle.net/8Qsp8/13/

You need this jQuery:

```
$("#slider").mouseover(function () {
    $(".slide2").stop().animate({bottom: '100px'});
});

$("#slider").mouseout(function () {
    $(".slide2").stop().animate({bottom:'-100px'});
});
```

Comment: Oops. Updated. Thanks @DavidThomas

Comment: Works almost as I want! Thanks ;)